# If $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are four positive real numbers then which are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are four positive real numbers such that $$x_1+\frac{1}{x_2}=4\\x_2+\frac{1}{x_3}=1\\x_3+\frac1{x_4}=4\\x_4+\frac1{x_1}=1$$ then which of the following is true

1. $x_1=x_3$
2. $x_4=x_2$
3. $x_1x_2=1$
4. $x_3x_4=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system has a unique solution, which is easy to find, namely
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(2,1/2,2,1/2).
$$
This answers the question.

Comment: How did you solve it ? Please show the steps

Comment: By elimination (start with last equation, and eliminate $x_4$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint rather than solving verify options. You will get options $1,3,4$ are correct $x_3=2,x_4=1/2$ and then further $x_1=1/2,x_2=2$  so $x_1x_2=1,x_3=x_1$